# Why is the pacman game pausing automatically for few seconds and then again running?

Tags: java, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I was trying the Pacman game with Q-Learning(Reinforcement learning) in java.
However, I could see the game was pausing automatically for a few seconds and then again running. I just wanted to know the reason for this.

Youtube Video link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bmDTAX13so4&feature=youtu.be

Github link for code https://github.com/iamarkaj/pacman-Q_learning

Board.java :

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Dimension d;
    private final Font smallFont = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 14);

    private Image ii;
    private final Color dotColor = new Color(192, 192, 0);
    private Color mazeColor;

    private boolean inGame = true;
    private boolean dying = false;

    private final int BLOCK_SIZE = 24;
    private final int N_BLOCKS = 15;
    private final int SCREEN_SIZE = N_BLOCKS * BLOCK_SIZE;
    private final int PAC_ANIM_DELAY = 2;
    private final int PACMAN_ANIM_COUNT = 4;
    private final int MAX_GHOSTS = 12;
    private final int PACMAN_SPEED = 6;

    private int pacAnimCount = PAC_ANIM_DELAY;
    private int pacAnimDir = 1;
    private int pacmanAnimPos = 0;
    private int N_GHOSTS = 6;
    private int score;
    private int[] dx, dy;
    private int[] ghost_x, ghost_y, ghost_dx, ghost_dy, ghostSpeed;

    private Image ghost;
    private Image pacman1, pacman2up, pacman2left, pacman2right, pacman2down;
    private Image pacman3up, pacman3down, pacman3left, pacman3right;
    private Image pacman4up, pacman4down, pacman4left, pacman4right;

    private int pacman_x, pacman_y, pacmand_x, pacmand_y;
    private int req_dx, req_dy, view_dx, view_dy;

    private final short levelData[] = {
            19, 26, 26, 26, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 22,
            21, 0, 0, 0, 17, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 20,
            21, 0, 0, 0, 17, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 20,
            21, 0, 0, 0, 17, 16, 16, 24, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 20,
            17, 18, 18, 18, 16, 16, 20, 0, 17, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 20,
            17, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 20, 0, 17, 16, 16, 16, 16, 24, 20,
            25, 16, 16, 16, 24, 24, 28, 0, 25, 24, 24, 16, 20, 0, 21,
            1, 17, 16, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17, 20, 0, 21,
            1, 17, 16, 16, 18, 18, 22, 0, 19, 18, 18, 16, 20, 0, 21,
            1, 17, 16, 16, 16, 16, 20, 0, 17, 16, 16, 16, 20, 0, 21,
            1, 17, 16, 16, 16, 16, 20, 0, 17, 16, 16, 16, 20, 0, 21,
            1, 17, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 18, 16, 16, 16, 16, 20, 0, 21,
            1, 17, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 20, 0, 21,
            1, 25, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 16, 16, 16, 18, 20,
            9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 25, 24, 24, 24, 28
    };

    private final int validSpeeds[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8};
    private final int maxSpeed = 6;

    private int currentSpeed = 3;
    private short[] screenData;
    private Timer timer;
    
    private int[][][] Q = new int[60][60][6];
    private int action;
    private double lr;
    private int step = 0;
    private int x_state;
    private int y_state;
    private int key = 1;
    private int seed = 0;
    
    public Board() {

        loadImages();
        initVariables();
        initBoard();
    }

    private void initBoard() {
        
        addKeyListener(new TAdapter());

        setFocusable(true);

        setBackground(Color.black);
    }

    private void initVariables() {

        screenData = new short[N_BLOCKS * N_BLOCKS];
        mazeColor = new Color(5, 100, 5);
        d = new Dimension(400, 400);
        ghost_x = new int[MAX_GHOSTS];
        ghost_dx = new int[MAX_GHOSTS];
        ghost_y = new int[MAX_GHOSTS];
        ghost_dy = new int[MAX_GHOSTS];
        ghostSpeed = new int[MAX_GHOSTS];
        dx = new int[4];
        dy = new int[4];

        timer = new Timer(40, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void addNotify() {
        super.addNotify();

        initGame();
    }

    private void doAnim() {

        pacAnimCount--;

        if (pacAnimCount <= 0) {
            pacAnimCount = PAC_ANIM_DELAY;
            pacmanAnimPos = pacmanAnimPos + pacAnimDir;

            if (pacmanAnimPos == (PACMAN_ANIM_COUNT - 1) || pacmanAnimPos == 0) {
                pacAnimDir = -pacAnimDir;
            }
        }
    }

    private void playGame(Graphics2D g2d) {

        if (dying) {

            death();

        } else {

            movePacman();
            drawPacman(g2d);
            moveGhosts(g2d);
            checkMaze();
        }
    }

    private void drawScore(Graphics2D g) {

        String s;

        g.setFont(smallFont);
        g.setColor(new Color(96, 128, 255));
        s = "Score: " + score;
        g.drawString(s, SCREEN_SIZE / 2 + 96, SCREEN_SIZE + 16);

    }

    private void checkMaze() {

        short i = 0;
        boolean finished = true;

        while (i < N_BLOCKS * N_BLOCKS && finished) {

            if ((screenData[i] & 48) != 0) {
                finished = false;
            }

            i++;
        }

        if (finished) {

            score += 50;

            if (N_GHOSTS < MAX_GHOSTS) {
                N_GHOSTS++;
            }

            if (currentSpeed < maxSpeed) {
                currentSpeed++;
            }

            initLevel();
        }
    }

    private void death() {

        inGame = true;
        initLevel();

    }

    private void moveGhosts(Graphics2D g2d) {

        short i;
        int pos;
        int count;
        
        for (i = 0; i < N_GHOSTS; i++) {
            if (ghost_x[i] % BLOCK_SIZE == 0 && ghost_y[i] % BLOCK_SIZE == 0) {
                pos = ghost_x[i] / BLOCK_SIZE + N_BLOCKS * (int) (ghost_y[i] / BLOCK_SIZE);
                count = 0;

                if ((screenData[pos] & 1) == 0 && ghost_dx[i] != 1) {
                    dx[count] = -1;
                    dy[count] = 0;
                    count++;
                }

                if ((screenData[pos] & 2) == 0 && ghost_dy[i] != 1) {
                    dx[count] = 0;
                    dy[count] = -1;
                    count++;
                }

                if ((screenData[pos] & 4) == 0 && ghost_dx[i] != -1) {
                    dx[count] = 1;
                    dy[count] = 0;
                    count++;
                }

                if ((screenData[pos] & 8) == 0 && ghost_dy[i] != -1) {
                    dx[count] = 0;
                    dy[count] = 1;
                    count++;
                }

                if (count == 0) {

                    if ((screenData[pos] & 15) == 15) {
                        ghost_dx[i] = 0;
                        ghost_dy[i] = 0;
                    } else {
                        ghost_dx[i] = -ghost_dx[i];
                        ghost_dy[i] = -ghost_dy[i];
                    }

                } else {
                    
                    Random rand = new Random(seed);
                    seed += 1;
                    double prob2 = rand.nextInt(10)+2;
                    double prob2_ = 1/prob2;

                    count = (int) (prob2_ * count);

                    if (count > 3) {
                        count = 3;
                    }

                    ghost_dx[i] = dx[count];
                    ghost_dy[i] = dy[count];
                }

            }

            ghost_x[i] = ghost_x[i] + (ghost_dx[i] * ghostSpeed[i]);
            ghost_y[i] = ghost_y[i] + (ghost_dy[i] * ghostSpeed[i]);
            drawGhost(g2d, ghost_x[i] + 1, ghost_y[i] + 1);

            if (pacman_x > (ghost_x[i] - 12) && pacman_x < (ghost_x[i] + 12)
                    && pacman_y > (ghost_y[i] - 12) && pacman_y < (ghost_y[i] + 12)
                    && inGame) {

                dying = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void drawGhost(Graphics2D g2d, int x, int y) {

        g2d.drawImage(ghost, x, y, this);
    }

    private void movePacman() {

        int pos;
        short ch;

        if (req_dx == -pacmand_x && req_dy == -pacmand_y) {
            pacmand_x = req_dx;
            pacmand_y = req_dy;
            view_dx = pacmand_x;
            view_dy = pacmand_y;
        }

        if (pacman_x % BLOCK_SIZE == 0 && pacman_y % BLOCK_SIZE == 0) {
            pos = pacman_x / BLOCK_SIZE + N_BLOCKS * (int) (pacman_y / BLOCK_SIZE);
            ch = screenData[pos];

            if ((ch & 16) != 0) {
                screenData[pos] = (short) (ch & 15);
                score++;
            }

            if (req_dx != 0 || req_dy != 0) {
                if (!((req_dx == -1 && req_dy == 0 && (ch & 1) != 0)
                        || (req_dx == 1 && req_dy == 0 && (ch & 4) != 0)
                        || (req_dx == 0 && req_dy == -1 && (ch & 2) != 0)
                        || (req_dx == 0 && req_dy == 1 && (ch & 8) != 0))) {
                    pacmand_x = req_dx;
                    pacmand_y = req_dy;
                    view_dx = pacmand_x;
                    view_dy = pacmand_y;
                }
            }

            // Check for standstill
            if ((pacmand_x == -1 && pacmand_y == 0 && (ch & 1) != 0)
                    || (pacmand_x == 1 && pacmand_y == 0 && (ch & 4) != 0)
                    || (pacmand_x == 0 && pacmand_y == -1 && (ch & 2) != 0)
                    || (pacmand_x == 0 && pacmand_y == 1 && (ch & 8) != 0)) {
                pacmand_x = 0;
                pacmand_y = 0;
            }
        }
        pacman_x = pacman_x + PACMAN_SPEED * pacmand_x;
        pacman_y = pacman_y + PACMAN_SPEED * pacmand_y;
        
        x_state = pacman_x*60/380;
        y_state = pacman_y*60/420;
        
        step += 1;
        if (step % 500 == 0) {
            System.out.println(step);
        }
        lr  = Math.pow(0.85, (step/100));  
        Q[x_state][y_state][action] += lr * (score + Q[x_state][y_state][action]);
        
    }

    private void drawPacman(Graphics2D g2d) {

        if (view_dx == -1) {
            drawPacmanLeft(g2d);
        } else if (view_dx == 1) {
            drawPacmanRight(g2d);
        } else if (view_dy == -1) {
            drawPacmanUp(g2d);
        } else {
            drawPacmanDown(g2d);
        }
    }

    private void drawPacmanUp(Graphics2D g2d) {

        switch (pacmanAnimPos) {
            case 1:
                g2d.drawImage(pacman2up, pacman_x + 1, pacman_y + 1, this);
                break;
            case 2:
                g2d.drawImage(pacman3up, pacman_x + 1, pacman_y + 1, this);
                break;
            case 3:
                g2d.drawImage(pacman4up, pacman_x + 1, pacman_y + 1, this);
                break;
            default:
                g2d.drawImage(pacman1, pacman_x + 1, pacman_y + 1, this);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void drawPacmanDown(Graphics2D g2d) {

        switch (pacmanAnimPos) {
            case 1:
                g2d.drawImage(pacman2down, pacman_x + 1, pacman_y + 1, this);
                break;
            case 2:
                g2d.drawImage(pacman3down, pacman_x + 1, pacman_y + 1, this);
                break;
            case 3:
                g2d.drawImage(pacman4down, pacman_x + 1, pacman_y + 1, this);
                break;
            default:
                g2d.drawImage(pacman1, pacman_x + 1, pacman_y + 1, this);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void drawPacmanLeft(Graphics2D g2d) {

        switch (pacmanAnimPos) {
            case 1:
                g2d.drawImage(pacman2left, pacman_x + 1, pacman_y + 1, this);
                break;
            case 2:
                g2d.drawImage(pacman3left, pacman_x + 1, pacman_y + 1, this);
                break;
            case 3:
                g2d.drawImage(pacman4left, pacman_x + 1, pacman_y + 1, this);
                break;
            default:
                g2d.drawImage(pacman1, pacman_x + 1, pacman_y + 1, this);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void drawPacmanRight(Graphics2D g2d) {

        switch (pacmanAnimPos) {
            case 1:
                g2d.drawImage(pacman2right, pacman_x + 1, pacman_y + 1, this);
                break;
            case 2:
                g2d.drawImage(pacman3right, pacman_x + 1, pacman_y + 1, this);
                break;
            case 3:
                g2d.drawImage(pacman4right, pacman_x + 1, pacman_y + 1, this);
                break;
            default:
                g2d.drawImage(pacman1, pacman_x + 1, pacman_y + 1, this);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void drawMaze(Graphics2D g2d) {

        short i = 0;
        int x, y;

        for (y = 0; y < SCREEN_SIZE; y += BLOCK_SIZE) {
            for (x = 0; x < SCREEN_SIZE; x += BLOCK_SIZE) {

                g2d.setColor(mazeColor);
                g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));

                if ((screenData[i] & 1) != 0) {
                    g2d.drawLine(x, y, x, y + BLOCK_SIZE - 1);
                }

                if ((screenData[i] & 2) != 0) {
                    g2d.drawLine(x, y, x + BLOCK_SIZE - 1, y);
                }

                if ((screenData[i] & 4) != 0) {
                    g2d.drawLine(x + BLOCK_SIZE - 1, y, x + BLOCK_SIZE - 1,
                            y + BLOCK_SIZE - 1);
                }

                if ((screenData[i] & 8) != 0) {
                    g2d.drawLine(x, y + BLOCK_SIZE - 1, x + BLOCK_SIZE - 1,
                            y + BLOCK_SIZE - 1);
                }

                if ((screenData[i] & 16) != 0) {
                    g2d.setColor(dotColor);
                    g2d.fillRect(x + 11, y + 11, 2, 2);
                }

                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    private void initGame() {

        score = 0;
        initLevel();
        N_GHOSTS = 6;
        currentSpeed = 3;
    }

    private void initLevel() {

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < N_BLOCKS * N_BLOCKS; i++) {
            screenData[i] = levelData[i];
        }

        continueLevel();
    }

    private void continueLevel() {
        
        score = 0;
        short i;
        int dx = 1;
        int random;

        for (i = 0; i < N_GHOSTS; i++) {

            ghost_y[i] = 4 * BLOCK_SIZE;
            ghost_x[i] = 4 * BLOCK_SIZE;
            ghost_dy[i] = 0;
            ghost_dx[i] = dx;
            dx = -dx;
            
            Random rand = new Random(0);
            double prob1 = rand.nextInt(10)+2;
            double prob1_ = 1/prob1;
            
            random = (int) (prob1_ * (currentSpeed + 1));

            if (random > currentSpeed) {
                random = currentSpeed;
            }

            ghostSpeed[i] = validSpeeds[random];
        }

        pacman_x = 7 * BLOCK_SIZE;
        pacman_y = 11 * BLOCK_SIZE;
        pacmand_x = 0;
        pacmand_y = 0;
        req_dx = 0;
        req_dy = 0;
        view_dx = -1;
        view_dy = 0;
        dying = false;
    }

    private void loadImages() {

        ghost = new ImageIcon("src/resources/images/ghost.png").getImage();
        pacman1 = new ImageIcon("src/resources/images/pacman.png").getImage();
        pacman2up = new ImageIcon("src/resources/images/up1.png").getImage();
        pacman3up = new ImageIcon("src/resources/images/up2.png").getImage();
        pacman4up = new ImageIcon("src/resources/images/up3.png").getImage();
        pacman2down = new ImageIcon("src/resources/images/down1.png").getImage();
        pacman3down = new ImageIcon("src/resources/images/down2.png").getImage();
        pacman4down = new ImageIcon("src/resources/images/down3.png").getImage();
        pacman2left = new ImageIcon("src/resources/images/left1.png").getImage();
        pacman3left = new ImageIcon("src/resources/images/left2.png").getImage();
        pacman4left = new ImageIcon("src/resources/images/left3.png").getImage();
        pacman2right = new ImageIcon("src/resources/images/right1.png").getImage();
        pacman3right = new ImageIcon("src/resources/images/right2.png").getImage();
        pacman4right = new ImageIcon("src/resources/images/right3.png").getImage();

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        doDrawing(g);
    }

    private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height);

        drawMaze(g2d);
        drawScore(g2d);
        doAnim();

        if (inGame) {
            playGame(g2d);
        }

        g2d.drawImage(ii, 5, 5, this);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        g2d.dispose();
    }

    class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {
 
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            
            Robot r = null;
            try {
                r = new Robot();
            } catch (AWTException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            
            Random rand = new Random();
            int prob = rand.nextInt(100)+1;
            if (step < 500000) {
                if (prob < 90) {
                    key = rand.nextInt(5)+1;
                    action = key;}
                else {
                    int max = Q[x_state][y_state][0];
                    action = 1;
                    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {  
                       if(Q[x_state][y_state][i] > max) {
                           action = i;
                           key = i;}
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                int max = Q[x_state][y_state][0];
                action = 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {  
                   if(Q[x_state][y_state][i] > max) {
                       action = i;}
                }
            }
            if (inGame) {
                if (key == 1) {
                    req_dx = -1;
                    req_dy = 0;
                } else if (key == 2) {
                    req_dx = 1;
                    req_dy = 0;
                } else if (key == 3) {
                    req_dx = 0;
                    req_dy = -1;
                } else if (key == 4) {
                    req_dx = 0;
                    req_dy = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        repaint();
    }
}
```

Pacman.java:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Pacman extends JFrame {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Pacman() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        add(new Board());

        setTitle("Pacman");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(380, 420);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {

            var ex = new Pacman();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like optimalization issues, few things which i did find:

1. You don't need to draw everything each time for example

   g.setColor(Color.black);

   g.fillRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height);

Can be called only once. Or when you will recreate maze.

2. drawMaze - Is it really possible that each of that if statement will be fired? if not then use if else in order which will occur more often to the less often
3. You should probably drop using Graphics2D as it have less performance than Graphics out of the box. Or read more about performance while using it
4. For me removing Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync(); improved performance (less pausing)

So in general it's all about performance, try changing graphics2d to graphics and replace pacman and ghost with squares, you will see if it's better then

Edit: I was playing with some snake AI before, not sure if it will help you but you can check it here: https://github.com/Morph21/AI

It's not the prettiest code ever so don't jugde me